# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI []in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' error when deploying in Jboss 6.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-deployment, jboss6.x

When i trying to deploy my project in jboss 6.4 its deployed and when request with url its give error No mapping found for HTTP request with URI  in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'.
I use spring boot version 1.4.7.RELEASE.

```
15:11:08,693 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:11:08,693 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) started in 8962ms - Started 519 of 557 services (60 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
15:11:25,429 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mobitel-merchant-app]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
15:11:25,430 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
15:11:25,444 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 12 ms
15:11:25,461 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) inside index call controller
15:11:25,478 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/merchant-app/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
15:11:25,483 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

This is my pom

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>lk.merchantApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>merchant-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>merchant app external</name>

  <properties>

  <java.version>1.8</java.version>

  </properties>


  <parent> 
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>


    <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>


            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>

           <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

             </exclusions>


    </dependency>







<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.8-ea03</version>
        </dependency>



    <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>



 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>     










    </dependencies>

     <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

  </plugin>

  </plugins>
  </build> 






</project>
```

and this is my application properties .

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**

spring.resources.add-mappings=true


server.servlet-path=/*



#web.server.https.port=8090
server.port=8080
```

This is my jboss-deployement-structure

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <exclusions>
          <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
          <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>

<module name="org.jboss.resteasy"/>

<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
      </exclusions>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and this is my jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/merchant-app</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Please help me .

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace, also which URL do you call?

Comment: localhost:8080/merchant-app this was called and give above error on jboss log

Comment: @Jens I updated with stacktrace error